# Possibly two rewrite being matched in my htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite the following 2 URLs to 2 different pages

```
/potato/prakash.raman ----> /potato/user.php?handle=prakash.raman
/potato/prakash.raman/watchlist ----> /potato/watchlist.php?handle=prakash.raman
```

These are my rewrites

```
ReWriteRule ^(.*)/watchlist watchlist.php?handle=$1
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?handle=$1
```

Both seem to getting rewritten to user.php?handle

What could I be doing wrong. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `RewriteCond` to guard against rewriting existing files, and add the `[L]` flag to ensure no further rules are matched after the first match:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReWriteRule ^(.*)/watchlist watchlist.php?handle=$1 [L]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?handle=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, although like I mentioned in the edited-answer. I had to add the RewriteCond before both the rules. Is there a way I can have a condition apply to a group of rules ?